# OpenAM 12.0 XUI javascript error

Tags: openam

OpenAM 11.0.0 works quite well.

But when I try a clear installtion of OpenAM 12.0.0, I encounter JavaScript error in XUI which prevents me to login.

[image]

But the network tab says all resources are loaded.
[image]

Is this a bug or because of my installation?

Answer (score 0):

After executing the following command, the default login page can be shown now

```
/openam/tools/admin/openam/bin/ssoadm set-attr-defs -s iPlanetAMAuthService -t Global --adminid amadmin --password-file /tmp/pwd.txt -a openam-xui-interface-enabled=false
```

However, if appending `module=xx` parameter, it happens again.

Comment: What happens again? Legacy UI is not AJAX based.

If you get an OpenAM error, set debug mode to 'message' and have a look into OpenAM debug log files.